# Why can I use the comparison limit test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2}\left(\cos \frac{1}{n}-e^{\frac{-1}{2 n^{2}}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to understand why I can use  the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)
on the following series: $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2}\left(\cos \frac{1}{n}-e^{\frac{-1}{2 n^{2}}}\right)
$$

In the book they didn't mention why the expression $
n^2(\cos \frac{1}{n}-e^{\frac{-1}{2 n^{2}}})>0
$
which is obviuosly not

Comment: But it's always negative, so comparison test applies as well.

Comment: @DominikKutek I don't think you need that all summands have the same sign.

Comment: I've never said one needs it. I've just said it's sufficient to apply comparison test, which is more than enough in this example.

Comment: Can you explain why the expression in the series is always negative? I cannot see that

Comment: Firstly, it is worth mentioning that it is enough to show $\cos(\frac{1}{n}) - e^{-\frac{1}{2n^2}} < 0$ for $n$ big enough (you can forget about fixed number of terms). By letting $x= \frac{1}{n}$, it is enough to show that $\cos(x) - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is negative if $x$ is close to $0$. To this end, use taylor expansions of $\cos,\exp$ to see that the above is $-Cx^4 + o(x^4)$ near $x=0$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I am sorry but if $f(x)$ is approach zero as x goes to zero, than its mean that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for small $x's$ this is not gurantee that $f(x)$ is none negative

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansion with peano form of remainder? As I said, $\cos(x) - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} = -Cx^4 + o(x^4) = x^4 \left(-C + \frac{o(x^4)}{x^4}\right)$. Since by definition of $o(\cdot)$, we have $\frac{o(x^4)}{x^4} \to 0$, we see that for $x$ small enough, $-C + \frac{o(x^4)}{x^4}$ is negative, hence $\cos(x)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ for $x$ small enough is negative.

Comment: @DominikKutek Now I understood what you meant, thank you kindly for the explantations

Answer (score 0):

The comparison test is helpful to prove that a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is *absolutely convergent*. The sufficient condition is that there exists a real sequence $(b_n)$ such, that

$$
1) \lvert a_n \rvert \le b_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \\
2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \text{ converges absolutely.}
$$

(Notice that $b_n \ge 0 \forall n$ follows from the first condition. So the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ is automatically absolute.)

So I guess you should look out for a sequence $(b_n)$ which dominates the absolute value of $(a_n) := n^2 (\cos \frac1n - \exp \frac{-1}{2n^2})$.